# Unfortunately application has stopped but continues when OK is clicked

Tags: android

I have application with 20 activities. 
When I run the application in my phone, it runs softly from activity 1 to 18. But in the 18th activity when I click the OK in alert dialog, my application has stopped. But when I click the OK, the application continues and returns me to activity 17. And in the 18th activity when I click OK from the dialog box in continues to 18th activity.

But when i run the application to my emulator, it works perfectly fine.

Here's my code in my 17th activity

```js
public class Luzon8Trivia extends Activity {
 private Button nextQ8;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.luzon8_trivia);
  
  Intent intent=getIntent();
  int myValue=intent.getIntExtra("parameter name", 0);
  final int answer=myValue + 10;
  nextQ8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNextQuestion);
  nextQ8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(Luzon8Trivia.this, Luzon09.class);
    intent.putExtra("parameter name", answer);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.transition_fade_in, R.animator.transition_fade_out);}
  });
 }
}
```

And here's my code in 18th activity

```js
public class Luzon09 extends Activity {
 private int currentQuestion;
 private String [] answers;
 private Button answerButton;
 private TextView scoreTxt, showClue;
 private EditText answerText;
 int newCoin, myValue;
 int newScore, newScore2=0;
 private Button luz9he1, luz9he2, luz9he3;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.luzon09);
  Intent intent=getIntent();
  int myValue=intent.getIntExtra("parameter name", 0);
  newCoin=myValue;
  scoreTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
  scoreTxt.setText("" + newCoin);
  
  showClue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtviewClue);
  
  //accepts user input
  answerText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
  
  init2();
  
  luz9he1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz1);
  luz9he1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     if (newCoin>=10){
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Luzon09.this);
               builder.setTitle("Need some Help?");
               builder.setMessage("Using Help will deduct your Peso Coin by 20. Are you sure?");
               builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
               builder.setPositiveButton("YES",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     newCoin-= 20;
                     scoreTxt.setText("" + newCoin);
                     luz9he1.setEnabled(false);
            showClue.setText("The province has been known as the Historical Capital of the Philippines");
                    return;  }
                               });// +
               builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       }
      });
               AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
         alert.show(); 
        }
          else {Toast.makeText(Luzon09.this, "You have insufficient coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
   }
  });//end of help 1
  
  luz9he2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz11);
  luz9he2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     if (newCoin>=10){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Luzon09.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need some Help?");
                builder.setMessage("Using Help will deduct your Peso Coin by 20. Are you sure?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      newCoin-= 20;
                      scoreTxt.setText("" + newCoin);
              luz9he2.setEnabled(false);
             showClue.setText("It is surrounded by Laguna province to the east, Metro Manila to the northeast, and Batangas province to the south.");
                     return;  }
                                }); //+
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show(); 
         }
           else { Toast.makeText(Luzon09.this, "You have insufficient coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
     }
    });//end of help 2
  
  luz9he3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz111);
  luz9he3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     if (newCoin>=10){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Luzon09.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need some Help?");
                builder.setMessage("Using Help will deduct your Peso Coin by 20. Are you sure?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      newCoin-= 20;
                      scoreTxt.setText("" + newCoin);
             luz9he3.setEnabled(false);
             showClue.setText("It is one of the most industrialized and one of the fastest growing provinces in the country.");
                     return;  }
                                }); //+
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show(); 
          }
           else {Toast.makeText(Luzon09.this, "You have insufficient coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
     }
    });//end of help 2

  
 }

 public void onBackPressed() {
  startActivity(new Intent(Luzon09.this, MainMenu.class));
  finish();
     return;
 }
 public void init2()
 {
 //correct answer
 answers=new String[]{"Cavite"};
 
 //accepts user input
 answerText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
 
 //checks if the answer is correct
 answerButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
 answerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   checkAnswer();
  }
 });
 }
 
 public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
 { return(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion])); }

 public void checkAnswer()
 { String answer=answerText.getText().toString(); 

  if(isCorrect(answer))
  {  
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("What are you a GENIUS?!");
            builder.setMessage("Nice one, Genius! You have P10!");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
            builder.setPositiveButton("View Trivia",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             String userData=scoreTxt.getText().toString();
             int userNumber=Integer.parseInt(userData);
             Intent intent=new Intent(Luzon09.this, Luzon09Trivia.class);
             intent.putExtra("parameter name", userNumber);
             startActivity(intent);
             overridePendingTransition(R.animator.transition_fade_in, R.animator.transition_fade_out);
             ;} });
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
           alert.show(); // Show Alert Dialog
        scoreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         
                 //disable all the buttons and textview
        answerText.setEnabled(false);
        answerButton.setClickable(false);  
           }
       else 
       {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       
      }
      }
```

Pardon me for the long code.

Comment: You can't check the logcat? Then what use is this emulator?

Comment: are you compiling the app from Android Studio or Intellij?

Comment: no. i'm using eclipse. i'll check the logcat.

Comment: It might be that your app is consuming too much resources. Can you show us some code to have a better idea?. To begin: call the finish(); method right after your StartActivity(...) methods, and check if the app still crashes. Share your logcat to see where the error is, there might also be a problem with your Activity #17.

Comment: @Rami the app. works perfectly fine in the emulator, but when run on phone my app has stopped.

Comment: When you run/debug the app in phone and it stop, check the LogCat

Comment: @Rami my phone isn't recognized by eclipse, what im doing is to install the app to my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Menifest file, whether you write activity for activity18 or not

```
<activity android:name="activity_name"></activity>
```

and for Emulate App directly to Phone, you have to write

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

in menofest file after

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

then connect your phone to pc and enable USB debuging.

Comment: activity 18 is included. ill try your second solution. thank u.